# Error in Jackson custom Serializers/Deserializers

Tags: java, android, jackson

in order to sort out the problems in the custom Serializers/Deserializers I carried out it to another project
it make such a mistake

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(288): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.MyActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can not create generator for non-byte-based target

https://i.stack.imgur.com/roNBf.jpg

program files:

MyActivity.java

```
package com.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.example.JacksonObject;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.*;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

String jacksonString = "{\"DateField\":\"/Date(61283424600000)/\",\"StringField\":\"STRING_string\",\"DoubleField\":\"87.12345\",\"IntegerField\":\"387\"}";
try {
    MyJsonWrapper sss = new MyJsonWrapper();

    JacksonObject[] mailItems2 = sss.getMyJson().readValue(jacksonString, JacksonObject[].class);
    int a2 = 3;  //это просто так, что бы поставить точки!!!
    int  b = a2; //это просто так, что бы поставить точки!!!

}   catch (JsonGenerationException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

} catch (JsonMappingException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

} catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

}
int a = 3; //это просто так, что бы поставить точки!!!
int s = 10; //это просто так, что бы поставить точки!!!
s = s + a; //это просто так, что бы поставить точки!!!
}
}
```

JacksonObject.java

```
package com.example;

import java.util.Date;

public class JacksonObject
{
public Date DateField;
public String StringField;
public Double DoubleField;
public int IntegerField;
}
```

MyJsonWrapper.java

```
package com.example;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser;
import org.codehaus.jackson.Version;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.*;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.module.SimpleModule;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonDeserializer;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonSerializer;
import org.codehaus.jackson.smile.*;
import org.codehaus.jackson.*;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.*;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.NullSerializer;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Date;

public class MyJsonWrapper
{

public ObjectMapper getMyJson()
{
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new SmileFactory());        
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("MyModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null));

module.addSerializer(Date.class, new JsonDateSerializer());
module.addDeserializer(Date.class, new JsonDateDeserializer());

mapper.registerModule(module);

return mapper;
}

public class JsonDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date>
{

public Date deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
{
    try {

    String s = jp.getText().replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "");

    if (s.equals("")) return null;

    boolean isDateBefore1970 = false;

    ............................................

    if (isDateBefore1970)
        return new Date(-Long.valueOf(s) - offset * 60 * 1000);
    else
        return new Date(Long.valueOf(s) + offset * 60 * 1000);

    }catch (JsonMappingException e){
        // If a JSON Mapping occurs, simply returning null instead of blocking things
        return null;
    }

  }
  }

  public class JsonDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date>
 {
   public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)   throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
  {            
    jgen.writeString("/Date(" + date.getTime() + ")/");
  }
 }    
 }
```

and when in My JsonWrapper.java use static instead of public

```
 public class MyJsonWrapper
{
 public static ObjectMapper getMyJson()
{        
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new SmileFactory());        
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("MyModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null));

module.addSerializer(Date.class, new JsonDateSerializer());
module.addDeserializer(Date.class, new JsonDateDeserializer());

mapper.registerModule(module);

return mapper;
}

static class JsonDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date>
{

public Date deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
{
    try {
```

tnen it makes such a mistake

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.MyActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can not create generator for ......

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tN7Q.jpg

line with the error

```
JacksonObject[] mailItems2 = sss.getMyJson().readValue(jacksonString, JacksonObject[].class);
```

Comment: jackson looks so crazy. try google's GSON: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out, SmileFactory supports binary Smile encoding (see [this wiki page](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonForSmile)), which has same structure as JSON (but much more compact, faster to process), but is not textual and not JSON. It must be written as bytes, and not as Java characters.

EDIT: 2018-06-19 -- Same is true for all binary format codecs -- Avro, CBOR, Protobuf (and BSON via `bson4jackson`, MsgPack via `jackson-dataformat-msgpack`), not just Smile.

So use regular JsonFactory instead if you want JSON; or, if you do want Smile, provide byte target: `OutputStream` is the most common choice (like `ByteArrayOutputStream`).

Comment: Got here because of similar issue with CBORFactory and the solution also worked for my case. 6 years later but thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using `SmileFactory`? It doesn't support reading from or writing to non-byte targets (in your case you're trying to read from a string).